# Extracting a specific substring from a specific hyper-reference using Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python, and for my second attempt at a project, I wanted to extract a substring – specifically, an identifying number – from a hyper-reference on a url.

For example, [this url](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=1932&playercomp=white&pid=&player=Alekhine&pid2=&player2=Naegeli&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=&eco=&result=1%2F2-1%2F2) is the result of my search query, giving the hyper-reference http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1012809. From this I want to extract the identifying number "1012809" and append it to navigate to the url http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1012809, after which I plan to download the file at the url http://www.chessgames.com/pgn/alekhine_naegeli_1932.pgn?gid=1012809 . But I am currently stuck a few steps behind this because I can't figure out a way to extract the identifier.

Here is my MWE:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=1932&playercomp=white&pid=&player=Alekhine&pid2=&player2=Naegeli&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=&eco=&result=1%2F2-1%2F2'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
import re
y = str(soup)
x = re.findall("gid=[0-9]+",y)
print x
z = re.sub("gid=", "", x(1))  #At this point, things have completely broken down...
```

Comment: what's the use of beautifulsoup here btw?

Comment: `re.findall()` returns a list  x ,you are trying to call the list like a function `x(1)` which is wrong you can get first value by writing  `x[0]`

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have upvoted your answers, though they won't display because I haven't built up >15 reputation yet.

Comment: If either of the answers does the trick, make sure to choose that as your selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Albin Paul commented, `re.findall` return a list, you need to extract elements from it. By the way, you don't need `BeautifulSoup` here, use `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()` to get the string of the content, and the `re.sub` is also not needed here, one regex pattern `(?:gid=)([0-9]+)` is enough.

```
import re
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=1932&playercomp=white&pid=&player=Alekhine&pid2=&player2=Naegeli&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=&eco=&result=1%2F2-1%2F2'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

result = re.findall(r"(?:gid=)([0-9]+)",page)

print(result[0])
#'1012809'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex here at all. Css selector along with string manipulation will lead you to the right direction. Try the below script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_link = 'http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=1932&playercomp=white&pid=&player=Alekhine&pid2=&player2=Naegeli&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=&eco=&result=1%2F2-1%2F2'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page_link).text, 'lxml')
item_num = soup.select_one("[href*='gid=']")['href'].split("gid=")[1]
print(item_num)
```

Output:

```
1012809
```